# Selenium in Python stops execution after automatic download

Tags: python, selenium, firefox

I'm trying to automate several downloads with selenium. I've set my downloads such that when a pop-up appears the download happens automatically. It just so happens that even after the download is done execution just hangs.

```
downloadLink = download.get_attribute("href")
print("Download starting")
driver.get(downloadLink)
print("Download stop")
```

"Download stop" never prints

Comment: Can you try adding `driver.set_page_load_timeout(30)` and use a try except block around the get download link?

Comment: It does kind of work, although it's no ideal as it cancels the download if I don't estimate the time right

Comment: You have to specify a timeout, without that it is hard to stop it and you can try to set it to 120 or higher, because if you want to wait for page to load then you will have to do that

Comment: I was facing the same issue, changed to chrome (v54) and chromedriver(v2.25) and it is working great. Have you tried that or you really need to go with firefox and geckodriver?

Comment: I don't really need to use Selenium. Let me try chromedriver instead and see how it turns out